# How can i play byte array of audio using mediaplayer .c#

Tags: c#, media-player

**i upload audio file to my sqlserver and i want to retrieve from it and play with mediaplayer**

error is:   Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'string' test

```
 byte[] sound = null;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select music from music where ID=1", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            sound = (byte[])dr["music"];
        }
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = sound;
```

Comment: What are you saving in your database? The file OR the URL to the file?

Comment: i convert audio file to binary and save in database , and i want to retrieve and play with mediaplayer..

Comment: the answer is below, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your music Column is of the type (VARBINARY(MAX)) here is a working code:

```
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select music from music where ID=1", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                {
                    if (dr.FieldCount > 0)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            var columnIndex = dr.GetOrdinal("music");
                            var stream = dr.GetSqlBinary(columnIndex);                                
                            var memStream = new MemoryStream(stream.Value);
                            var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                            IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = memStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
                            mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(randomAccessStream, "audio/mpeg");
                            mediaPlayer.Play();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Error CS1061 'MemoryStream' does not contain a definition for 'AsRandomAccessStream' and no extension method 'AsRandomAccessStream' accepting a first argument of type 'MemoryStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CreateFromStream' and no extension method 'CreateFromStream' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I gave you the answer, if you can't figure out how to add packages to solve dependencies I strongly recommend you to follow a C# course.